# How can I generate a cryptographically strong sequence of random bytes from a seed?

Tags: c#, random, cryptography, prng

How can I generate a sequence of cryptographically strong random bytes from a seed value (so that the sequence can be regenerated from the same seed again)? Are there maybe any good CSPRNG algorithms that I could implement in C# (preferably with good documentation)?

Niether the [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) or [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class will fulfill my requirments, since `Random` isn't  cryptographically strong and `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` won't allow you to set the seed value.

Comment: Assuming it is for testing - why not to have special implementation that just returns well known sequence of numbers? (otherwise how repeatable sequence can be "cryptographically strong"?)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Because I need to generate a different sequence based on the seed. The `Random` class would of been fine, if it was cryptographically strong.

Comment: A random generator being cryptographically secure implies that the numbers cannot be predicted. Also, numbers (or bytes) [cannot be random](http://xkcd.com/221/) – the generator is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is perfect for the job, most often it is used as a password hashing function, however you can request as many bytes as you want from it and it will always return the same series of bytes for a given seed (the combination of password, salt, and iteration count)

Here is the example from the MSDN that shows two instances of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` returning the same sequence for both (by using the first sequence to encrypt a a block of data with symmetric encryption and using the 2nd sequence to decrypt it).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class rfc2898test
{
    // Generate a key k1 with password pwd1 and salt salt1. 
    // Generate a key k2 with password pwd1 and salt salt1. 
    // Encrypt data1 with key k1 using symmetric encryption, creating edata1. 
    // Decrypt edata1 with key k2 using symmetric decryption, creating data2. 
    // data2 should equal data1. 

    private const string usageText = "Usage: RFC2898 <password>\nYou must specify the password for encryption.\n";
    public static void Main(string[] passwordargs)
    {
        //If no file name is specified, write usage text. 
        if (passwordargs.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(usageText);
        }
        else
        {
            string pwd1 = passwordargs[0];
            // Create a byte array to hold the random value.  
            byte[] salt1 = new byte[8];
            using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                // Fill the array with a random value.
                rngCsp.GetBytes(salt1);
            }

            //data1 can be a string or contents of a file. 
            string data1 = "Some test data";
            //The default iteration count is 1000 so the two methods use the same iteration count.
            int myIterations = 1000;
            try
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes k1 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1, myIterations);
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes k2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1);
                // Encrypt the data.
                TripleDES encAlg = TripleDES.Create();
                encAlg.Key = k1.GetBytes(16);
                MemoryStream encryptionStream = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream encrypt = new CryptoStream(encryptionStream, encAlg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                byte[] utfD1 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(data1);

                encrypt.Write(utfD1, 0, utfD1.Length);
                encrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                encrypt.Close();
                byte[] edata1 = encryptionStream.ToArray();
                k1.Reset();

                // Try to decrypt, thus showing it can be round-tripped.
                TripleDES decAlg = TripleDES.Create();
                decAlg.Key = k2.GetBytes(16);
                decAlg.IV = encAlg.IV;
                MemoryStream decryptionStreamBacking = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream decrypt = new CryptoStream(decryptionStreamBacking, decAlg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                decrypt.Write(edata1, 0, edata1.Length);
                decrypt.Flush();
                decrypt.Close();
                k2.Reset();
                string data2 = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetString(decryptionStreamBacking.ToArray());

                if (!data1.Equals(data2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: The two values are not equal.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The two values are equal.");
                    Console.WriteLine("k1 iterations: {0}", k1.IterationCount);
                    Console.WriteLine("k2 iterations: {0}", k2.IterationCount);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: ", e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's quite slow with iterations=1 and abysmally slow with a 1000 iterations. If you consume more than 20 bytes from PBKDF2 with a significant number of iterations, you're probably doing something wrong.